# How to link against GLFW on Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am looking to learn how to use OpenGL with C++, and I am following the tutorial at [open.gl](https://open.gl/). I am at [this](https://open.gl/context) part in the tutorial, and I am using GLFW. I tried following the instructions to build GLFW,

> After you've downloaded the GLFW binaries package from the website or
> compiled the library yourself, you'll find the headers in the include
> folder and the libraries for your compiler in one of the lib folders.
>
> -Add the appropriate lib folder to your library path and link with GLFW.
>
> -Add the include folder to your include path.

I downloaded it, and moved the include folder into my MinGW include folder, but I was unsure where to find the lib folder, how to add it to my library path, or how to link it with OpenGL. This was not explained in the tutorial, and I could not find any instruction online about what this meant or how to do it. I proceeded without doing the other two steps, and when attempting to run the test code from the tutorial:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I received this error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread:35:0,
                 from D:\Files\Documents\Programming\opengl_tut.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I added -std=c++11 to my compiler flags, and I received this error:

```
D:\Files\Documents\Programming\opengl_tut.cpp: In function 'int main()':
D:\Files\Documents\Programming\opengl_tut.cpp:7:10: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Thinking the problem might just be with std::this_thread, I removed that line from my program, and ran it to see if initializing and terminating GLFW would return any errors. I got this:

```
C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCJrDGj.o:opengl_tut.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCJrDGj.o:opengl_tut.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCJrDGj.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think this may be because of the fact that I skipped earlier parts of the tutorials.

**TL;DR**

- Tried to follow tutorial to use OpenGL
- Couldn't figure out how to link GLFW
- Couldn't find lib folder
- Got errors relating to std::this_thread
- Got error relating to GLFW

**EDIT**

I found some info on the GLFW site saying to use Cmake. I downloaded it and tried using it to build from the downloaded files. It made a new folder, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: The last thing is a linker error. It tells you that you have to link your program against the appropriate glfw library.  [Look here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)

Comment: *Never* install anything (headers, libraries, etc.) into your compiler toolchain's installation directory. Always create a separate directory tree for third party libraries (headers, sources, binaries) and configure that directory to be part of your compiler's and linker's search paths.

Comment: Why? I already put my headers in the same directory as my compiler.

Comment: @Bretsky when you later need to update the compiler or the OpenGL for that matter it is easier to have them in separate locations, e.g. delete old directory and reinstall new version.

Comment: @CyberSpock could you help me with fixing this error? I am really lost and have no idea how to do any of this linking stuff.

Comment: @Bretsky do you have a make file?

Comment: @CyberSpock I have Cmakelists.txt, and some cmake.in files. I used Cmake and it made a second folder.

Answer (score 0):

- First, it's easy to do such config in Visual Studio, just NuGet, and search glfw, install, Visual Studi/NuGet will handle everything like set proper Include path, Additional Library path, add additional library files
- Second, it looks like your link issue, try to add these to your gcc cmd line

  - `g++ -o example.exe example.o -L. -lexample_dll`
- Third, check the glfw library you downloaded, use `MinGW-w64` lib files. Also remember distinguish the static and dynamic libs

Comment: What is the difference between static and dynamic libs?

Comment: I couldn't find any lib files at all in my GLFW folder.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, and I couldn't find any lib files, so I am still unsure how to do this.

Comment: Oh, I think you just download the source code of glfw, you should build it from source codes to lib files. If you don't want to, choose `Windows pre-compiled binaries` in http://www.glfw.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've downloaded the source files. This will require building (using CMake). You should go download the precompiled binaries. To do this, go back to glfw.org and instead of hitting the download button on the home page, go to the download tab in the top right and under "Windows pre-compiled binaries" select the 32 or 64 bit version and click download. [See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRG7r.jpg)

Then, when you extract from the .zip folder you should find in it several folders - the include folder, as well folders with names beginning with "lib" (like lib-mingw, lib-mingw-w64, lib-vc2010, lib-vc2012, etc). You only need one of them, which depends on the compiler you're using - minGW or Visual C++ (vc). Choose the appropriate folder and inside you should find .lib and .dll files.

Now, whenever you compile your OpenGL program, you must tell the compiler (the linker, really) to link those files to your program's object files. You do this by using the proper compiler command line arguments. You can read about doing that in MinGW here: http://mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

For that tutorial you'll probably only need to link glfw3.lib (for MSVC) or libglfw3.a (for MinGW). If you're using GLEW, you'll probably just need glew32.lib and glew32.dll (the latter is found in the "bin" folder not the "lib" folder).

Hope that helps answer your question.